# OpenERP 7 service start issue

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.2, openerp-7

I installed OpenERP 7 in my CentOS 64 bit and I have this problem when starting the service:

```
            Starting OpenERP Server Daemon (openerp-server):           [  OK  ]
            root@****[~]# ERROR: couldn't create the logfile directory. Logging to the standard output.
            2014-09-10 14:04:58,739 29029 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140804-231303
            2014-09-10 14:04:58,739 29029 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/openerp/addons
            2014-09-10 14:04:58,739 29029 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
            2014-09-10 14:04:58,739 29029 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
            2014-09-10 14:04:58,740 29029 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/usr/bin/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
            pkg_resources.run_script('openerp==7.0-20140804-231303', 'openerp-server')
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 461, in run_script
            self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1194, in run_script
            execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
            openerp.cli.main()
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 61, in main
            o.run(args)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/openerp/cli/server.py", line 272, in run
            main(args)
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/openerp/cli/server.py", line 252, in main
            setup_pid_file()
            File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/openerp-7.0_20140804_231303-py2.6.egg/openerp/cli/server.py", line 88, in setup_pid_file
            fd = open(config['pidfile'], 'w')
            IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/openerp/openerp-server.pid'
```

Also when I Try to stop the service I have this error:

```
            service openerp stop
            Stopping OpenERP Server Daemon (openerp-server): cat: /var/run/openerp/openerp-server.pid: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Can you please advise how to fix this issue?

Thank you,
Best Regards,

Comment: This issue is come from the automatic openerp-server script. Please check out script of that. And also give permission to `var/run/openerp` folder. For example go to `cd /var/run/` and than `chmod 777 openerp`

Comment: Thank you Odedra, two question please: 1-what do you mean with the automatic openerp-server script? and is it secure to give chmod 777 for this folder?

Comment: Auto script means how you run openerp server. Like you hit command in terminal or whenever system is start, openerp-server will also start. May I know how you run server? And for second question, This error indicate user may not have right for writing `/var/run/openeerp` in this script. If we give 777 for that user than might be error will not trigger.

Comment: Thank you again, I will review the /var/run/openeerp and I will let you know the result soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a Permission issue, Your hint solve my problem, All what I did is gave correct Permission for the ERP user to the /var/run/openerp/openerp-server.pid., Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Odedra said, its an permission issue as well as missing python modules and I found no reason for why this happens from the start, but at least I got hint how to solve is as the following:

1- I found missing python and other modules must be installed in my Cent OS 6.5 and it was:

```
yum -y install python-psycopg2 python-lxml PyXML python-setuptools libxslt-python pytz \
python-matplotlib python-babel python-mako python-dateutil python-psycopg2 \
pychart pydot python-reportlab python-devel python-imaging python-vobject \
hippo-canvas-python mx python-gdata python-ldap python-openid \
python-werkzeug python-vatnumber pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil \
python-matplotlib pygtk2 glade3 pydot python-dateutil python-matplotlib \
python python-devel python-psutil python-docutils make\
automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel byacc flashplugin-nonfree poppler-utils pywebdav\
```

2- After this I fix the permission issue by doing the following:

- chown USERNAME:USERNAME/var/run/openerp/openerp-server.pid
- sudo chown USERNAME:USERNAME/tmp/oe-sessions-openerp

Please note the following:

1- Be sure where you installed your openerp as not by defualt you will find your path in /tmp.

After doing the following my problem has been solved.